# Remove object from a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove specific element from a javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-a-javascript-array)

Specifically I have an array as follows:

```
var arr = [
    {url: 'link 1'},
    {url: 'link 2'},
    {url: 'link 3'}
];
```

Now you want to remove valuable element url "link 2" and after removing the only arrays as follows:

```
arr = [
    {url: 'link 1'},
    {url: 'link 3'}
];
```

So who can help me this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: I do not think this is a a direct duplicate of that question. In the other question only a primitive value is used. `indexOf` will **not** work here. So, unless the index is (always) known, a bit of the puzzle is missing with `splice`...

Comment: I have seen this question many times already.

Comment: `arr.filter(function(element){
return(element.url === 'link 2'? false :true);
})`

Comment: var arr = [
  {url: "link 1"},
  {url: "link 2"},
  {url: "link 3"}
];

arr = arr.filter(function(el){
  return el.url !== "link 2";
});

Answer (score 35):

You could do a filter.

```
var arr = [
  {url: "link 1"},
  {url: "link 2"},
  {url: "link 3"}
];

arr = arr.filter(function(el){
  return el.url !== "link 2";
});
```

***PS:*** [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is mplemented in JavaScript 1.6, supported by most modern browsers, If for supporting the old browser, you could write your own one.

Comment: Please include the requirements... not everyone is so lucky to have such function (without a shim).

Comment: Perfect, helped me allot!

Answer (score 4):

Use the splice function to remove an element in an array:

```
arr.splice(1, 1);
```

If you would like to remove an element of the array without knowing the index based on an elements property, you will have to iterate over the array and each property of each element:

```
for(var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    for(var b in arr[a]) {
        if(arr[a][b] === 'link 2') {
            arr.splice(a, 1);
            a--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```